# 'NoneType' object is not callable django cms

Tags: django, django-views, django-cms

I want to store data from template that is not in same directory as views.
My form is located in `mysite/style.html`  <-data inserted in this form, I want to pass them in models from another app called "services".

/mysite/   is my root directory.

```
 <form name = "form" action="{% url 'services.views.add_style' %}" method = "POST" class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="style" name="name" placeholder="style" type="style" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="color" type="color" required>
        </div>

        <input class="form-control" id="positions" name="positions" placeholder="positions" type="positions" required>
        <input class="form-control" id="font_size" name="font_size" placeholder="font_size" type="font_size" required>
        <input class="form-control" id="background" name="background" placeholder="background" type="background" required>
        <input class="form-control" id="font" name="font" placeholder="font" type="font" required>
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

than I have separated app called "services"

Here is views.py

```
def add_style(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        style = request.POST.get('style')
        color = request.POST.get('color')
        positions = request.POST.get('positions')
        font_size = request.POST.get('font_size')
        background = request.POST.get('background')
        font = request.POST.get('font')
        Model = style(style=style, color=color, positions=positions, font_size=font_size, background=background, font=font)
        Model.save()

    return redirect('/')
```

and models.py

```
class style(CMSPlugin):
        style = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        color=RGBColorField(max_length=30)
        positions = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        font_size = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        background = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        font = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.style
```

Traceback shows error in this line

```
 Model = style(style=style,  positions=positions, font_size=font_size, background=background, font=font)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the HTML form you are using :
In this line :

```
  <input class="form-control" id="style" name="name" placeholder="style" type="style" required>
```

The name attribute of  is defined as **name** but in your views.py,you are using :

```
 style = request.POST.get('style')
```

So the correct HTML form should be :

```
<form name = "form" action="{% url 'services.views.add_style' %}" method = "POST" class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="style" name="style" placeholder="style" type="style" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="color" type="color" required>
  </div>

  <input class="form-control" id="positions" name="positions" placeholder="positions" type="positions" required>
  <input class="form-control" id="font_size" name="font_size" placeholder="font_size" type="font_size" required>
  <input class="form-control" id="background" name="background" placeholder="background" type="background" required>
  <input class="form-control" id="font" name="font" placeholder="font" type="font" required>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a class named `style` and also a local variable named `style` that overrides that name.

```
class style(CMSPlugin):
    ...

style = request.POST.get('style')  # this is None, and also overrides your class 
...
Model = style(style=style, color=color,)  # you are trying to call None()
```

If you followed the convention on naming classes with title case, you would have avoided this bug.

```
class Style(CMSPlugin):  # Title case
    ...

style = request.POST.get('style')  # No shadowing of other variable 
...
model = Style(style=style, color=color,)
```

Comment: Django also has ModelForm exactly for cases like this, when the form corresponds directly to a model.